# Issue with bot adding server members to its membercount | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My bot got added to a 4.9k server and everytime i ran the "zbotstats" or restarted the console it didn't add those 4.9k members what is the issue here?

[image]

Before the 4.9k server was added it had 3.8k which shouldve added up to 8.7k

My code for guild user count:

```
  console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online on ${bot.guilds.cache.size} servers!`);
    console.log(`lovell is looking over ${bot.users.cache.size} users`)
```

**Using: Discord.v12**

Comment: Are you sure that those 4981 users aren't already in a guild with the bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `bot.users.cache.size` is the number of **cached** users. And not all the users of all the guilds are cached. So, how to fix?

#### First way: cache ALL the members

You can use the following code to force discord.js to cache all the members in all the servers:

```js
const bot = new Discord.Client({ fetchAllMembers: true });
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(client.guilds.cache.size); // right count
});
```

You will see that `bot.users.cache.size` will be the right count. Note that this way will cost a lot of RAM if your bot starts to be on a lot of big servers.

#### Second way: use `guild.memberCount` instead of the cache

You can use:

```js
const users = bot.guilds.cache.map((guild) => guild.memberCount).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
console.log(users); // right count
```